# writing to a file in Java using printWriter by two ways, which one is better and why?

Tags: java, io, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I have the following methods that creates and writes to that file.

```
// Create the file and the PrintWriter that will write to the file

    private static PrintWriter createFile(String fileName){

        try{

            // Creates a File object that allows you to work with files on the hardrive

            File listOfNames = new File(fileName);


            PrintWriter infoToWrite = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(listOfNames);
            return infoToWrite;
        }

        // You have to catch this when you call FileWriter

        catch(IOException e){

            System.out.println("An I/O Error Occurred");

            // Closes the program

            System.exit(0);

        }
        return null;

    }
```

The program works fine, even if I dont have `bufferedWriter and FileWriter` like below. how does they two objects help in making the writing process better? I can avoid creating two objects in this case.

```
PrintWriter infoToWrite = new PrintWriter((listOfNames);
```

Comment: One of the issues seen using `PrintWriter` is that you will have to flush the data manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

> In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying
> character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is
> advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write()
> operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.
>
> If you're writing large blocks of text at once (like entire lines)
> then you probably won't notice a difference. If you have a lot of code
> that appends a single character at a time, however, a BufferedWriter
> will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you may refer to the API document and you'll find the difference:

```
BufferedWriter:Writes text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and strings. 

FileWriter:Convenience class for writing character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.
```

if you want to create a file, the FileWriter will be better.